# Put a box on top of text

Tags: overlays

I'd like to put a box on top of some latex page (in my particular case, a slide of a beamer presentation), as indicated in the picture below. How do I achieve this in latex, preferable in a way where I just give absolute coordinates for the box, and not put the page in the background as a second argument.

[image]

**EDIT**: Ok, the tikz overlay option seems to do exactly what I want. I.e. adding

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[draw, fill=white, thick,minimum width=6cm,minimum height=4cm] (b) at (-4,0){Box with some content};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

to the page frame seems to solve the problem. I'll add this as an answer once I'm sure I won't run into unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Could you please give us a starting point?  A short example (maybe 20 to 40 lines) of a `beamer` presentation lacking your desired overlay box should suffice.

Comment: Yeah, I could. But the solution should be independent of the content of the slide. Just put a box on top of the current content of the slide, as shown on the Image, that I can hide/unhide using \only<>{}.

Comment: The tikzpagenodes will allow you to place a box (called a node in tikz) anywhere of the page relative to points like (current page text area.center).  You may have to fill the node with white first.